# Problems populating 3D cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to populate a 3D cell array. Here is the code:

```
D = cell(M,N,1); 

for i = 1:M
    for j=1:N
       for k = 1:L
           D{i}{j}(1+length(D{i}{j})) = 1;   % error here
       end 
    end
end
```

I get the error `Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object` even though the following within the command window works fine:

```
D{i}{j}(1+length(D{i}{j})) = 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is how you are indexing your cell array `D`.  The syntax is

```
D{i,j,k}
```

not

```
D{i}{j}{k}
```

The line giving an error should therefore be written

```
D{i,j,1 + length(D{i,j})} = 1;
```

For more information see [Access Data in a Cell Array](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).

Comment: To elaborate, `D{i}{j}{k}` does mean something, but it means nesting cell array within a cell array within a cell array.

Comment: Thought it has got rid of the error, the size of `D` is `M x N x 2`, but it should be `M x N x L`. Is there something wrong in the answer in you suggested?

Comment: @dr_rk To simply populate the array with ones, use `D{i,j,k} = 1`.  Presently you're iterating over `k = 1:L` but not using the variable `k` anywhere.  I would also suggest initialising the array with `D = cell(M,N,L)`.  If you're still having problems I'd suggest starting a new question with more details of the problem you're trying to solve; at the moment it's not entirely clear what your objective is.